# publish asp.net application on windows 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7

I have an asp.net project and I want to install it on iis in another computer 
with windows 7(this computer doesn't contain VS)

what I need to install for upload this web site???

and how I upload this web site in iis7?

Thanks

Comment: Upload means hosting?

Comment: its mean publish on iis

Comment: Publish is the word used by vs to host the application on iis. So here publish or hosting, both refer same.

Comment: ok how i do it ?????????????

Comment: but how i deploy it on iis? how can i show it from the broweser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hosting application on iis In windows7. Please follow the steps.

> 1. Open inetmgr.
> 2. Create new appool for your application. The apppool version should be equivalent or greater than the version in which you developed the
>      application.
> 3. Right click on default site and create virtual directory.
> 4. Select the apppool you created for the application in dropdown.
> 5. Give the physical path of your application and Alas name to call your application from browser.

After that you can configure default document, authentication etc.. based on your need.

Then, browse the application to make sure it works.

I hope your windows 7 has iis installed and asp.net is registered in iis. If not, please install the same and regester iis with aspnet_regiis and a option -i Before start hosting.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i

For hosting, vs not needed. Windows 7 comes with .net 4.0 by default.

For more details, please refer iis.net site or msdn site for step by step process with graphical example.

Comment: how i install "regester iis with aspnet_regiis and a option -i Before start hosting"?

Comment: Please refer my answer in this thread for registerring .net in iis. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246021/how-to-host-an-asp-net-web-applications-site-on-iis-7/15246362#15246362